# Locate the Upcoming Expiry date and Assign the Value based on it - Python Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook

There are two dataframes, need to extract the Nearest upcoming Expiry date from Dataframe2 based on Active date in Dataframe 1 to obtain the correct Value.

This is a sample. Original data contains thousands of rows

Dataframe 1

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A','B'],
               'Active date': ['2021-06-20','2021-06-25']})
```

[image: Dataframe 1]

Dataframe 2

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'Expiry date': ['2021-05-22','2021-06-23','2021-06-24','2021-06-28','2021-07-26','2021-06-27','2021-06-28','2021-08-29'],
                'Value': [20,21,23,45,12,34,17,34]})
```

[image]

Final Output -

[image]

The code I was trying -

```
df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='Category', how='inner')
#Removed all the dates which are less than Active date
df = df.loc[(df_1['Active Date'] <= df_2['Expiry Date'])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this solution keeps a lot of your existing code and will accomplish what you are looking for.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A','B'],
               'Active date': ['2021-06-20','2021-06-25']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'Expiry date': ['2021-05-22','2021-06-23','2021-06-24','2021-06-28','2021-07-26','2021-06-27','2021-06-28','2021-08-29'],
                'Value': [20,21,23,45,12,34,17,34]})

df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='Category', how='inner')

# Removed all the dates which are less than Active date
df = df.loc[(df['Active date'] <= df['Expiry date'])]
df = df.rename(columns={'Expiry date': 'Next Expiry Date'})
df = df.loc[df['Next Expiry Date'] == df.groupby('Category')['Next Expiry Date'].transform('min')]
```

Output:

```
  Category Active date Next Expiry Date  Value
1        A  2021-06-20       2021-06-23     21
5        B  2021-06-25       2021-06-27     34
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this, was not sure how to do the min in one single step. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, please accept this as the solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas `merge_asof` with direction set to `forward`. Note that for `merge_asof`, both data frames must be sorted :

```
 df_1 = df_1.transform(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore')
 df_2 = df_2.astype({"Expiry date": np.datetime64})
 df_2 = df_2.sort_values('Expiry date')
 pd.merge_asof(df_1, 
               df_2, 
               left_on='Active date', 
               right_on='Expiry date', 
               direction='forward',
               by='Category')


        Category Active date Expiry date  Value
0        A       2021-06-20  2021-06-23     21
1        B       2021-06-25  2021-06-27     34
```

Comment: The sample I have created is very sorted and clean but the original dataset is not this clean. Merging based on date only might create some trouble. How can we bring Category in it @sammywemmy

Comment: you could merge on the category column with the `by` parameter